# How to change sql row order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have a table contain a column of 1 to 10 for each row. 
If I want to select from table that start from 8 then how can i change the order to according the sample output.

```
Sample output:
8
9
10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use expressions in the `order by`.  One method is:

```
order by (case when col >= 8 then 1 else 2 end),
         col asc
```

Answer (score 1):

For your scenario:

```
SELECT Col1 
FROM Your_Table
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN col1 < 8 THEN col1+10 ELSE col1 END)
```

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(col1 INT)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(2)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(3)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(4)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(5)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(6)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(7)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(8)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(9)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES(10)

SELECT Col1 
FROM @T
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN col1 < 8 THEN col1+10 ELSE col1 END)
```

**OutPut:**

```
Col1
8
9
10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below scenario for dynamic input for start value. I.e insted of start value of 8 if you want to start from 6 then also the below logic works.

```
DECLARE @tempTable TABLE(myColumn INT)
INSERT INTO @tempTable VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO @tempTable VALUES(2)
INSERT INTO @tempTable VALUES(3)
INSERT INTO @tempTable VALUES(4)
INSERT INTO @tempTable VALUES(5)
INSERT INTO @tempTable VALUES(6)
INSERT INTO @tempTable VALUES(7)
INSERT INTO @tempTable VALUES(8)
INSERT INTO @tempTable VALUES(9)
INSERT INTO @tempTable VALUES(10)
INSERT INTO @tempTable VALUES(11)
INSERT INTO @tempTable VALUES(12)
INSERT INTO @tempTable VALUES(13)
INSERT INTO @tempTable VALUES(14)
INSERT INTO @tempTable VALUES(15)
INSERT INTO @tempTable VALUES(16)

Declare @startValue Int = 12  --"YOUR_VALUE" [Ex: 8]
SELECT myColumn 
FROM @tempTable
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN myColumn < @startValue THEN myColumn+(select count(*) from @tempTable) ELSE myColumn END)
```

Let me know is that logic works for you or not? Thanks,